# Don't be trapped by dogma, which is living with the results of other people's thinking

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, antecedents, non-restrictive

From a speech by Steve Jobs:

> a. Don't be trapped by dogma, which is living with the results of other people's thinking.

If the sentence is to work syntactically, *dogma* has to be the antecedent of *which*.

*Dogma* is defined in [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dogma) as:

> A principle or set of principles laid down by an authority as incontrovertibly true.
>
> *He believes that when living in a certain society you should become a real part of it by **sticking to** its rules, dogmas and principles.*

So, *dogma* essentially is a set of principles determined by (i.e., results of)  other people's thinking. Also, from the LEXICO example, *sticking to its dogma* seems to correspond to *living with the results of other people's thinking*.

All in all, *dogma* itself seems to refer to "the results of other people's thinking" rather than "living with the results of other people's thinking".

If so, how come the antecedent of *which* can be *dogma*? Or should it be?

Comment: I would take it as referencing "dogma".  Often the determination of antecedents must be a little flexible.

Comment: Yes it is.  If you adhere to dogma you are living with the results of other people's thinking.

Comment: Don't be trapped by dogma.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be funny.

Comment: If you're trapped by dogma you've allowed yourself to be seduced into living with the results of other people's thinking (without questioning it).  It's the seduced without questioning part that is being "trapped", not the dogma per se.

Comment: I would take the antecedent of *which* to be “***trapped by dogma”.  Being trapped by dogma is living with the results of other people’s thinking.

Comment: @Jim That's also my reading. So the question is whether the relative _which_ can take _(be) trapped by dogma_ as subject of the relative clause. AFAIK, the relative _which_ can take a non-finite VP only if _which_ functions as complement of an auxiliary verb or _to_ in the relative clause, as in: _You shouldn't be trapped by dogma, which I once was._ (complement of the auxiliary _was_); _You shouldn't be trapped by dogma, which I wouldn't want anyone to._ (complement of _to_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supplementary relatives allow wide range of antecedents, including clauses. (CaGEL p1035):

> **Pat is afraid of snakes**, which doesn’t surprise me at all

The antecedent of the relativised element in the example given is:

> Don't **be trapped by dogma**, which is living with the results of
>   other people's thinking.

So he's saying that *being trapped by dogma* is *living with the results of other people's thinking*.

Comment: In your example, _which_ refers to the finite clause _Pat is afraid of snakes_. In (a), however, you're saying that _which_ refers to the non-finite clause _be trapped by dogma_.

Comment: That's also my reading. So the question is whether the relative _which_ can take _(be) trapped by dogma_ as subject of the relative clause. AFAIK, the relative _which_ can take a non-finite VP only if _which_ functions as complement of an auxiliary verb or _to_ in the relative clause, as in: _You shouldn't be trapped by dogma, which I once was._ (complement of the auxiliary _was_); _You shouldn't be trapped by dogma, which I wouldn't want anyone to._ (complement of _to_).

Comment: I don't see why the antecedent clause would be limited to a finite one. There are plenty of examples which could only be interpreted similarly to this this one. E.g. _Works had to **be transcribed by hand**, which was a slow and laborious operation_ where non-finite _transcribed by hand_ or _be transcribed by hand_ is clearly the antecedent.

Comment: Another example: _A clever advertising video, it has the potential to **be seen by millions**, which could result in a large increase in profits_

Comment: You're right. Thanks.